# Pattern for storing recurrent events that have their own data

Tags: database-design, architecture

I built a scheduling application that allows users to store recurrent events.
This is the (rather simplified) db design I came up with after a reading many related posts on the internet:

Table Appointment: holds info about a particular event on the calendar, and has a flag that indicates whether it is recurrent;

Table RRule: frequency (in days), start date , event duration, recurrence end date;

Now, if a record in the Appointment table is recurrent, I can build the future events by cloning the object and simply changing the start date of each one.

This has worked well for me for a while, despite the added complexity of building events from rules.

Now, I'm running into problems when I need to link other pieces of data to the recurrent events, because they don't actually exist in the database. I allow, for example, users to add an observation to each of their events, and since a recurrent event does not exist in the database, and the 'observation' column is part of the 'appointment' table, there is no easy way to accomplish separate observations for each recurrence.

Another problem: I'm currently implementing the financial control part of my system that will allow users to create a receipt for each appointment on their calendar, and because the recurrent events don't actually exist in my database, I have no way of linking them to their receipt, which is done via a foreign key column on the appointment table.

So here is my question: how would one go about adding specific information to recurrent events when using the well known rrule pattern?

I know google calendar allows you to add specific information to each recurring event, and even though you can create a daily event that 'never ends', it actually ends after about 2 years, which makes me feel like they replicate information instead of using rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two tables. `EventTemplate` & `EventInstance`. `EventTemplate` will hold information about recurrence of the Event. `EventInstance` will hold an entry for every event. You can either create an entry in database for every event instance and hold NULL for observation field`(INNER JOIN)` or just hold entries where there is an user entry for observation field`(LEFT JOIN)`.

So, it is recommended to have the EventInstance table in either case. But, storing the values, you can decide. I would suggest you to store NULL and maintain entry for every event instance. It makes the way to update the event, in case of future updates also and cleaner design.

Comment: Yeah... I'm afraid I will have to build another table to store specific information about each recurrence. Thing is: since the events don't actually exist, they have no primary key. Currently, I build a 'virtual' primary key based on the rrule id and the recurrence index inside the rule. Example: rule id 4, third ocurrence would have PK = "4-3", which is a real pain since all other primary keys are integers.

Comment: Why dont you generate a table now with primary key as `INT identity` and avoid virtual primary key. It could be one time activity. From now onwards, you can utilize this table for your needs.